# Is an imam required when making a marriage proposal?

Tags: nikah

Is an imam required when making a marriage proposal when the father and I already know each other well?

He has good knowledge of my character and deen and we often have long conversations and discussions on a variety of topics. We have a good relationship and know each other well.

I am seeking a non-Shia answer.

Comment: What is the Imam for? You'll need at least two witnesses and the guardian of the further wife or his agent and of course bride and ‏bridegroom a mahr or saddaq if you wanted it to be fixed one of the presents people could do so.

Answer (score 1):

Wa 'alaikum salaam.
I don't think Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) has given different laws for Shiya and Sunni.There is no such laws in Islam. Allah has given us one True Religion, and there is no different laws for different people

The answer is no. No imaam is required for a marriage.

**"One day Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) was walking in the street. And a Sahaabah came in that way. Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) asked him about his perfume he had on him. The Sahaabah replied that he married a girl yesterday. Then Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) asked about Mahr...etc"**

By the above Hadith, one Sahaabah married a girl without Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) knowledge and Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) didn't get angry for doing a marriage without him. This means There is no need for an Imaam in a Marriage

Comment: Be aware that the companions of the Prophet are called Sahaabah or sahaba or sahaaba or sahabah without "sh" this word is a plural and the singular is shababi or sahbiya in case of a female. (a Fem. plural is sahabiyyat) Note I wrote the last words in my preferred transliteration form so any of the 4 transliteration forms I used can be applied for the singular etc.